# Parse Error, On Site.MasterClass, Could Not Load Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, parse-error

I am getting a parsing error on the `Inherets = Site.MasterClass`. I am not entirely understanding what I need to updated in order for this error to go away. The entire site project worked excellent in Microsoft Visual Studios, it is just when I am trying to migrate the project via FTP that I am getting this error. Could it be the folder structure within the site that is causing the issue? Even when I change the folder's name from 'Across America' to "WingtipToys" I still get the same error.

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WingtipToys.SiteMaster'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
>   CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WingtipToys.SiteMaster" %> Line
>   2:   Line 3:
>
> Source File: /mydirectory/across-america/Site.Master    Line: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you ware copied the master from somewhere else, As it says `Inherits="WingtipToys....` if it is so then your master page will be under `WingtipToys` directory but the source says that it belongs to  `across-america`. So the `Inherits="WingtipToys.SiteMaster" %>` should be like this :

```
Inherits="across-america.SiteMaster" %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Can you tell me what the best practice is for placing the file? Must it be in the root directory? Now the error I am getting is " The file '/myfolder/Site.Master' does not exist."

Comment: Hope that the error shows when you are referring that master in a content page, Then use `..\` to choose the directory

Comment: No probs... Happy to help you